# Sagging ceiling post-repair

Tags: repair, ceiling, sagging

I had my hvac bust and put a hole below it in my kitchen ceiling from water damage (melting ice buildup from A/C). Had another area nearby that was sagging repaired as well. Hvac is now fixed, ceiling was repaired, but now I see this happening again in the same areas less than a month later.

It doesn't seem like water damage as I've had a snake camera up in the ceiling watching every time I use the plumbing upstairs or when the hvac is running(heat mode now and since repair).

So frustrated I spent over 2 grand fixing the ceiling only for it to happen again. Can anyone with experience possibly help me narrow this down? The hvac is above the area on the middle-right of the picture. The larger sag toward the corner is not where the HVAC is, but was the second area I had repaired.

[image: ceiling]

Comment: Check the condensate line from the AC to the outside or drain. It could be cracked and leaking a distance from the AC unit.

Comment: Was the ceiling area and all insulation thoroughly dried and/or replaced? If wet insulation was left up there, it could continue to drip out causing new damage.